# Let $G$ be a nilpotent group of class 3. Then for every $x ,y ,z$ in $G$, $[x,y,z][y,z,x][z,x,y]=1$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group of class 3. Then for every $x ,y ,z$ in $G$, $[x,y,z][y,z,x][z,x,y]=1$.

As $G$ is a nilpotent group of class 3, $[G,G,G,G]=1$ and $G^{'}$ is abelian.
I want to use Hall-Witt alliance but I don't know how to choose the elements.

Hall-Witt alliance : $[x,y^{-1},z]^{y}[y,z^{-1},x]^{z}[z,x^{-1},y]^{x}=1$

We have $[x,y,z,y^{-1}] =1$. So  $[x,y,z]=[x,y,z]^{y^{-1}}$. I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You need to prove that $[x,y^{-1},z] = [x,y,z]^{-1}$.  More generally, in a group of class $3$, triple commutators $[x,y,z]$ are linear in all three variables i.e. $[wx,y,z] = [w,y,z][x,y,z]$, etc.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your help.

Comment: This holds in any metabelian group, so in particular in a nilpotent group of class $3$, see [Lemma 6](http://people.bath.ac.uk/gt223/paper24.pdf).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde The identity is stated in the proof of that lemma but not proved.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I know. This should be left for the OP to find in the standard literature. I only wanted to give a help for this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you.

Comment: There are at least 4 conventions for the commutator ($[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, $bab^{-1}a^{-1}$, $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$, $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba$), and for each of them there are two conventions for the double commutator: $[[a,b],c]$ and $[a,[b,c]]$. So it's always good to recall which definition you choose (even if if probably the given equality hold for each of these 8 conventions).

Comment: With the convention $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$, there's a Hall identity $[a^b,[b,c]]\cdot[b^c,[c,a]]\cdot[c^a,[a,b]]$, which directly entails the desired equality in any metabelian group.

Comment: @YCor As a definition We choose $[[a,b],c]$.

Comment: And for the commutator?

Comment: @YCor $[a,b] = a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$

Comment: OK, so the Hall identity writes as $[a,b,c^a]\cdot [c,a,b^c]\cdot [b,c,a^b]=1$ (in any group).

Comment: @YCor It's originally written as a way I've written.You can search it.

Comment: I'm not talking of the Hall-Witt identity, but about another one due to Hall, which I wrote.

Comment: @YCor Oh sorry and thank you.